# Combinatorial Proof Technique

Tags: combinatorics, logic

I'm reading Cameron's *Combinatorics*, and am confused by the following Lemma, (which is used in his proof of the number of unordered selections without replacement). What is the name of this proof technique? Also why does the last sentence start with "conversely?" I don't see an implication of which to take the converse in the lemma.

Lemma 3.7.2 (pg 32): The number of choices of $k$ objects from $n$ with repetitions allowed and order not significant is equal to the number of ways of choosing $n$ non-negative integers whose sum is $k$.

Proof: Given a choice of $k$ objects from the set $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, let $x_i$ b the number of times that the given object $a_i$ gets chosen. Then $x_i \geq 0, \sum_{i=1} ^n x_i = k$. **Conversely**, given $(x_1,\ldots ,x_n)$, form a selection by choosing object $a_i$ just $x_i$ times. $\square $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof technique is basically the following: given two numbers, each of which is the cardinality of a finite set, prove that they are equal by providing a bijection between the sets; or, equivalently, by providing an injection from either set to the other.

In this case, the sets are $\{\text{choices of $k$ objects from $n$ with repetitions allowed}\}$ and $\{\text{n-tuples of nonnegative numbers which add up to k}\}$. The injection one way takes a choice of $k$ objects and produces a tuple, in such a way that different choices give different tuples; and the injection the other way takes a tuple and produces a choice, so that different choices produce different tuples.

Here, the "conversely" means something like "going in the other direction"; namely, you first go from the first set to the second, and then (conversely) from the second to the first.